# kubernetes kubectl Undo --insecure-skip-tls-verify to enable TLS Verification once again after it has been disabled

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, certificate, kubectl

For testing purposes I have disabled tls verification for my cluster by typing:

`$ kubectl get nodes --insecure-skip-tls-verify`

This was done to temporarily fix a problem with an invalid certificate.
Now that my certificate is valid again, I don't know how to enable tls verfication once again, without creating a completely new cluster.

I have already tried (without success):

`$ kubectl get nodes --insecure-skip-tls-verify=false`

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The default value of the `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` is false. Getting rid of the option flag **restores the default behavior** of TLS certificate verification. You can simply use the following command:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

Run the following command to check if TLS verification is being used:

```
kubectl config view
```

Verify that the `cluster` entry points to the correct cluster. Check if the `certificate-authority-data` field is present, it indicates that TLS verification is being used. The certificate data are omitted, to inspect the certificates display the complete Kubernetes configuration:

```
cat ~/.kube/config
```

Now, you can see and optionally verify (with `openssl` command) the certificates.